# ZipReplaceData.py ReplaceString

Tags: python, zip

How would you replace a string instead of replacing the entire
    content of hello.txt?

Is this possible?

It needs to {

findString('Hello');

ReplaceString('Hello', 'Goodbye');

}

**# file: ZipReplaceData.py**

```
import chilkat

# Open a zip, locate a file contained within it, replace the
# contents of the file, and save the zip.
zip = chilkat.CkZip()
zip.UnlockComponent("anything for 30-day trial")

success = zip.OpenZip("exampleData.zip")
if success:
    # The zip in this example contains these files and directories:
    # exampleData\
    # exampleData\hamlet.xml
    # exampleData\123\
    # exampleData\aaa\
    # exampleData\123\hello.txt
    # exampleData\aaa\banner.gif
    # exampleData\aaa\dude.gif
    # exampleData\aaa\xyz\  

    # Forward and backward slashes are equivalent and either can be used..
    zipEntry = zip.FirstMatchingEntry("*/hello.txt")
    if (zipEntry != None):
        # Replace the contents of hello.txt with something else.
        newContent = chilkat.CkString()
        newContent.append("Goodbye!")
        zipEntry.ReplaceData(newContent)

        # Save the Zip with the new content.
        zip.WriteZipAndClose()
    else:
        print "Failed to find hello.txt!\n"
else:
    # Failed to open the .zip archive.
    zip.SaveLastError("openZipError.txt")
```

Comment: which language are you using? you look like you've added tags for half the languages that exist... can you please just stick to the one you actually need, and remove the others? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the [string.replace()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) method for this job.

Sample code: The following code snippet will replace all the occurrences of `Hello` with `Bye`.

```
myString = 'Hello there! hello again.'
print myString.replace('Hello', 'bye')
```

Output: `bye there! hello again.`

PS: The above code will only replace the `Hello` word in which the `H` is capital. If you want to replace irrespective of the upper case/lower case letters then you may first convert the all letters to either Upper case or lower case and then use the `replace()`.

Sample code: This code will replace all the occurrences of `hello` word with `Bye`.

```
myString = 'Hello there! hello again.'
myString = myString.lower()# Convert to lower case
print myString.replace('hello', 'bye')
```

Output: `bye there! bye again.`

I hope it was helpful.